Why does shell script (.sh) give different results than command line for running Flask service with sudo?
I have a sequence of commands that I run from the command line. Here are the commands and output when run from the command line:
~/bettermult $ sudo systemctl stop bettermult
+ sudo systemctl stop bettermult
~/bettermult $ sudo systemctl start bettermult
+ sudo systemctl start bettermult
~/bettermult $ sudo systemctl status bettermult
+ sudo systemctl status bettermult
● bettermult.service - uWSGI instance to serve bettermult
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bettermult.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-05-08 01:06:53 UTC; 10s ago
   Main PID: 945740 (uwsgi)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 1132)
     Memory: 26.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bettermult.service
             ├─945740 /home/michael/bettermult/my-venv/bin/uwsgi --ini bettermult.ini
             ├─945752 /home/michael/bettermult/my-venv/bin/uwsgi --ini bettermult.ini
             ├─945753 /home/michael/bettermult/my-venv/bin/uwsgi --ini bettermult.ini
             ├─945754 /home/michael/bettermult/my-venv/bin/uwsgi --ini bettermult.ini
             ├─945755 /home/michael/bettermult/my-venv/bin/uwsgi --ini bettermult.ini
             └─945756 /home/michael/bettermult/my-venv/bin/uwsgi --ini bettermult.ini

    May 08 01:06:53 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945740]: *** Operational MODE: preforking ***
    May 08 01:06:53 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945740]: WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x5644d37f4bf0 pid: 945740 (default app)
    May 08 01:06:53 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945740]: *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
    May 08 01:06:53 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945740]: spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 945740)
    May 08 01:06:53 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945740]: spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 945752, cores: 1)
    May 08 01:06:53 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945740]: spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 945753, cores: 1)
    May 08 01:06:53 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945740]: spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 945754, cores: 1)
    May 08 01:06:53 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945740]: spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 945755, cores: 1)
    May 08 01:06:53 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945740]: spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 945756, cores: 1)
    May 08 01:06:55 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945753]: [pid: 945753|app: 0|req: 1/1] 185.242.226.7 () {36 vars in 509 bytes} [Wed May  8 01:06:55 2024] GET / => generated 25686 by>

That is the correct output. Note that it runs the desired five threads correctly.
Instead of typing those commands each time (actually up arrow on command line, but still), I made a file deploy.sh:
~/bettermult $ cat deploy.sh
+ cat deploy.sh
set -x
gzip -dkf deployment.tar.gz
tar -xf deployment.tar
sudo systemctl stop bettermult
sudo systemctl start bettermult
sudo systemctl status bettermult

In this case I get different output (whether I have to type in the sudo password as the script runs, or the system already has an active sudo password):
~/bettermult $ source deploy.sh
+ source deploy.sh
++ set -x
++ gzip -dkf deployment.tar.gz
++ tar -xf deployment.tar
++ sudo systemctl stop bettermult
++ sudo systemctl start bettermult
++ sudo systemctl status bettermult
● bettermult.service - uWSGI instance to serve bettermult
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bettermult.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-05-08 01:05:27 UTC; 68ms ago
   Main PID: 945702 (uwsgi)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 1132)
     Memory: 216.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/bettermult.service
             └─945702 [uwsgi]

May 08 01:05:27 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945702]: lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
May 08 01:05:27 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945702]: thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
May 08 01:05:27 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945702]: uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address bettermult.sock fd 3
May 08 01:05:27 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945702]: Python version: 3.8.10 (default, Nov 22 2023, 10:22:35)  [GCC 9.4.0]
May 08 01:05:27 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945702]: *** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
May 08 01:05:27 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945702]: Python main interpreter initialized at 0x562291f91bf0
May 08 01:05:27 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945702]: your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
May 08 01:05:27 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945702]: your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
May 08 01:05:27 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945702]: mapped 437520 bytes (427 KB) for 5 cores
May 08 01:05:27 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945702]: *** Operational MODE: preforking ***
May 08 01:05:28 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945702]: WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x562291f91bf0 pid: 945702 (default app)
May 08 01:05:28 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945702]: *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
May 08 01:05:28 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945702]: spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 945702)
May 08 01:05:28 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945702]: spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 945709, cores: 1)
May 08 01:05:28 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945702]: spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 945710, cores: 1)
May 08 01:05:28 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945702]: spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 945711, cores: 1)
May 08 01:05:28 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945702]: spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 945712, cores: 1)
May 08 01:05:28 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[945702]: spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 945713, cores: 1)

Several things are different from the command line output. For instance, it shows the Python version. More importantly, it gives a bunch of warnings about locks, no threading, limited backlog, and limited mercy.
I'm trying to understand why these differences. I was thinking maybe it was running a different version of python, but the version it lists is the same as the default from the command line:
~/bettermult $ python --version
+ python --version
Python 3.8.10

And my understanding is that a .sh script runs as me by default. So, why different?
Addition
Here's my run of ./deploy.sh as suggested by ubfan1 in the comments:
~/bettermult $ chmod +x ./deploy.sh
~/bettermult $ ./deploy.sh
++ gzip -dkf deployment.tar.gz
++ tar -xf deployment.tar
++ sudo systemctl stop bettermult
++ sudo systemctl start bettermult
++ sudo systemctl status bettermult
● bettermult.service - uWSGI instance to serve bettermult
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bettermult.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-05-08 11:43:51 UTC; 105ms ago
   Main PID: 957810 (uwsgi)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 1132)
     Memory: 5.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bettermult.service
             └─957810 /home/michael/bettermult/my-venv/bin/uwsgi --ini bettermult.ini

May 08 11:43:51 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[957810]: lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
May 08 11:43:51 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[957810]: thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
May 08 11:43:51 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[957810]: uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address bettermult.sock fd 3
May 08 11:43:51 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[957810]: Python version: 3.8.10 (default, Nov 22 2023, 10:22:35)  [GCC 9.4.0]
May 08 11:43:51 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[957810]: *** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
May 08 11:43:51 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[957810]: Python main interpreter initialized at 0x560c5795cbf0
May 08 11:43:51 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[957810]: your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
May 08 11:43:51 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[957810]: your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
May 08 11:43:51 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[957810]: mapped 437520 bytes (427 KB) for 5 cores
May 08 11:43:51 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc3-01 uwsgi[957810]: *** Operational MODE: preforking ***


If you run your script as ./deploy.sh (assuming your in the script's directory), what output do you get? The "source" command is not the normal way to run scripts, unless your script is changing your environment (setting env variables).

@ubfan1 Thanks for the suggestion. I used chmod to add x to deploy.sh and then ran ./deploy.sh. But it gave the same bad output. Well, actually slightly different. I've added it to the end of my question above.

What's the deal with these negative votes without a comment. I asked a sincere question about something I'm stuck on. Isn't this a Q/A site? What was wrong with my question?

Looks like the memory usage returned to the 5M, but tasks still 1.  The only difference that comes to mind is .bashrc, which (now) has explicit tests for "being interactive", and does different things. Try backing off a level to see what's going on -- bash -vx deploy.sh  (and start a subshell with bash -vx and redo the manual commands.   If bettermult does something similar...check their docs?

... as well, add a shebang to your deploy.sh script - I don't think it's a factor in this case (since you appear to be using bash) but in some cases which shell it runs in depends on the shell that you run it from. See for example Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?

D'oh!
Mystery solved.
Calling sudo systemctl start bettermult starts the service startup process, but the startup itself is asynchronous. So when sudo systemctl status bettermult runs, it shows the status of the server some number of milliseconds later.
It turns out that stuff about "Python threads support is disabled" was always being output, whether run manually or not. But systemctl status just shows the last n lines of the log. So when I did it manually and the server had time to spawn all the workers before I issued systemctl status, I saw all the workers and didn't see the higher-up threading error. In the script, the workers hadn't started yet, so I just saw the main service process, and saw those warning lines. My incorrect assumption was that systemctl status was showing me the "result" of the startup process, but in fact it always just shows the last n lines of the log.
New script that waits long enough to see the full start process:
set -x
gzip -dkf deployment.tar.gz
tar -xf deployment.tar
sudo systemctl stop bettermult
sleep 2s
sudo systemctl start bettermult
sleep 2s
sudo systemctl status bettermult
set +x

As for the "Python threads support is disabled." warning, that's still confusing to me. I do use python threading within my Flask python code, to trigger/handle periodic housekeeping tasks, and it seems to work fine. So I'm not sure how/where threads support is disabled. But that is for another question.
